# How do I stop search engines indexing a maintenance page

Tags: html, apache, header, web-crawler, metadata

I need to setup a maintenance page for a website I'm running, e.g. for display when I'm performing site maintenance (scheduled downtime) or if something really breaks and I need to put up a holding page.

Is there anything special I need to do to ensure that search engine crawlers don't index it and think that it's my site. Or should I do a 404, add a temporary robots.txt file or something? I basically don't want them to index it as my site, but I also don't want them to think my site is dead and not come back.

**Edit:** Here's what I did in Apache: ErrorDocument 503 /.server-maintenance.html RewriteEngine On RewriteRule !^.server-maintenance.html /server-maintenance Redirect 503 /server-maintenance**strong text**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should send a **`503 Service Unavailable`** HTTP status code, and not a **`404`**. Use this in conjunction with a **`Retry-After`** header to tell the robots when to come back.

Comment: As I still don't have enough rep to edit, here's what I did in Apache:

ErrorDocument 503 /.server-maintenance.html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^.server-maintenance.html /server-maintenance
Redirect 503 /server-maintenance

Answer (score 3):

You may use a robots.txt

http://www.robotstxt.org/

Also, google has a validator in their webmasters tools.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/

Answer (score 2):

Returning `503 Service Unavailable` tells Google bots to come back later. There's a Google [support page](http://google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=83040) describing the HTTP error codes and how they are interpreted by them.

You can also use [Retry-After response header](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/503-service-temporarily-unavailable.html) to suggest the minimum time after which your site is re-checked for availability.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to not link the maintenance page from any other page on your website (or any other website).